# How do I share my desktop PC internet with tablet/mobile?

Tags: wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, connection-sharing

How do I share my desktop PC internet with tablet/mobile?

I have a desktop PC with an internet connection. The connection is via Ruckus MM2211 (I think it's a gateway). I have a TPLINK TL-WN721N USB wifi adapter. Is it possible to share my desktop connection with my tablet?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wifi Hotspot using any software e.g mhotspot
share that with a WEP or a WPA2 key,
Use same info in the Tablet to connect your own wifi.

Comment: It created a hotspot but I am stuck at "Obtaining ip address" loop . What should I do ? Tried it on Galaxy Tab 3 T3110 ( non root , running preinstalled android ) and Galaxy S I9000 ( rooted running MIUI  android 2.3 )

Comment: Try another hotspot client...